# Swift - How to populate array

Tags: ios, swift

I want to send a post request to my API but I am having some issues with mapping.

The user starts on VCA and sees a list of users that is retrieved via GET request, the user can tap on a cell and see the details (VCB). on VCB, you can tap a cell again, and you get an action sheet which will update that status to available or unavailable. The issue I have is to populate the dailyInjuryStatus array in the POST request.

Get request model:

```
struct DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer: Hashable, Codable {
        var playerId: Int
        var playerName: String?
        var numberOfStatusMissingDays: Int
        var entries: [Entry]

        func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(playerId)
        }

        static func == (lhs: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer, rhs: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer) -> Bool {
            return lhs.playerId == rhs.playerId
        }
    }

    struct Entry: Codable {
        var injuryIllnessId: Int
        var injuryIllnessName: String?
        var statusDate: Date
        var modifiedBy: String?
        var status: String?
        var playerStatusId: Int
        var parentEventId: Int?
    }
```

The model for the POST

```
struct CreateDailyInjuryIllnessNote: Encodable {
        var teamId: UInt32
        var dailyInjuryIllnessStatus: [DailyInjuryIllnessStatus]

    }

    struct DailyInjuryIllnessStatus: Encodable {
        var iIeventId: UInt32
        var effectiveDate: Date
        var eventStatusId: UInt32
        var playerId: UInt32
    }
```

The code I am using for the request (Extracting the values from the screen to send to the API):

```
private extension DailyInjuryIllnessAPI.Model.Request.CreateDailyInjuryIllnessNote {

    static func from(playerId: Int?, statusNote: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer) -> Self? {
        guard let playerId = playerId else { return nil }
        let teamId = getTeamId(from: statusNote)

// Here is the issue, I can populate teamId, but I cannot populate dailyInjuryIllnessStatus.

        return .init(teamId: UInt32(teamId), dailyInjuryIllnessStatus: <#T##[DailyInjuryIllnessAPI.Model.Request.DailyInjuryIllnessStatus]#>)
        }


    private static func getTeamId(from model: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer) -> Int {
        let answer = model.playerId
        return answer
    }

    private static func getEventId(from model: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer) -> Int {
        var answer = 1
        for eventId in model.entries {
            answer = eventId.injuryIllnessId
        }

        return answer
    }

    private static func getEffectiveDate(from model: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer) -> Date {
        var answer = Date()
        for date in model.entries {
            answer = date.statusDate
        }
        return answer
    }

    private static func getEventStatusId(from model: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer) -> Int {
        var answer = 1
        for statusId in model.entries {
            answer = statusId.playerStatusId
        }
        return answer
    }

    private static func getPlayerId(from model: DailyInjuryIllnessPlayer) -> Int {
        var answer = model.playerId
        return answer
    }



    }
```

The issue as stated in the code is at the `return .init` Swift expects it to be like the model which has a teamId and an array of `DailyInjuryIllnessStatus`. How can I put the methods I used to extract those values into the array

Comment: Where is the array of `DailyInjuryIllnessStatus` supposed to come from? By the way, the loops in the other static methods seem to be pointless. Allways the last item of the loop is returned because the return value is overwritten.

Comment: @vadian the array comes from the API. It is how the API I structured.. is there a better way to do the loop

Comment: At the moment for example `getEffectiveDate` does the same as `return model.entries.last?.statusDate ?? Date()`

Comment: yes, ```getEffectiveDate``` should return the statusDate

Comment: It seems you don't understand. `model.entries` is an array with multiple items, each item contains a `statusDate`. Which one do you want to use? The code uses the last one, my suggestion is an optimized version of your code.

Comment: model.entries contains ``` var injuryIllnessId: Int
        var injuryIllnessName: String?
        var statusDate: Date
        var modifiedBy: String?
        var status: String?
        var playerStatusId: Int
        var parentEventId: Int?``` I need to extract each one.